# ReactNative TextInput placeholderTextColor doesn't seem to be working

Tags: react-native

It seems like such a simple thing, I don't see how I'm not getting this right, but *placeholderTextColor* on a ReactNative TextInput isn't doing anything for me.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#placeholdertextcolor

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder="Foobar"
    placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

does nothing....

Comment: Ok. Should have looked at the github issues first. Here's a thread for this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/294

Comment: I am still not able to get around it, id u find any solution?

Comment: @Ritveak If I remember right, those properties were broken in react native and have since been fixed. What version of RN are you using?

Comment: I am using 16.9 I think I am having trouble because I am using react-native-paper on top, so maybe it is masking the default TextInput props and that is why placeholderTextColor isn't working.

Answer (score 64):

This works -

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Enter password"
  placeholderTextColor="white"
/>
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: What version are you using. I haven't tried this is a while. Have they fixed it?

Comment: 0.8.0. Yeah, Its been fixed.

Comment: nope, doesn't work, and your code is sam as his, how is it supposed to help?

Answer (score 7):

```
 <TextInput
      value={this.state.environment}
      onChangeText={(environment) => this.setState({ environment })}
      placeholder={'Environment'}
      placeholderTextColor="#202020"
      secureTextEntry={true}
      style={styles.input}
      underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it works quite well:

```
// use standard input
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';


<TextInput
    style={[styles.searchInput, { opacity: this.state.location.length ? 1 : 0.6 }]}
    placeholder="Location"
    placeholderTextColor={colors.lighterGrey}
    onChangeText={location => this.setState({ location })}
    value={this.state.location}
/>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchInput: {
    flex: 1,
    lineHeight: 22,
    fontSize: 17,
    fontFamily: fonts.secondary.regular,
    color: colors.white,
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

I was having issues getting the opacity to work, so I found the above solution worked well as a minimal markup solution:

```
style={[styles.searchInput, { opacity: this.state.location.length ? 1 : 0.6 }]}
```

The style prop can accept an Array of style Objects which has right to left precedence, so you can override default styles with state-based addons. I might also say it is related to CSS specificity.

In my case, I was having trouble modulating the text colours between the placeholder text and 'filled-in text. The opacity of `styles.searchInput` was affecting the `<TextInput placeholderTextColor="">` prop.

My solution here handles the opacity concern on both iOS and Android and demonstrates a pretty normal `<TextInput>` setup.

In the context of my example code above, a person can always examine `this.state.location.length` to see if the field is empty or not.

If so, use TextInput's style prop with computed props (same as in Vue.js). You could drop a function in there, like:

```
style={[styles.textInput, calculatedStyles()]}
```

Don't forget you can spread in Objects also:

```
style={[...inputStyles, ...errorStyles]}
```

As Asanka Sampath shows in another answer, depending on your design, `underlineColorAndroid` can be a very useful TextInput prop.

Answer (score 3):

```
placeholder: "Enter password",
placeholderTextColor: "white"
```

try this in Latest Version in React Native

Comment: Worked for me. Setting the color did the trick!

Comment: placeholder: "Email"  is not a style property use this property in TextInput tag like this 
<TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="steelblue"
        />

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and easy solution**

```
 <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle} //if you want give style to the TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="steelblue"
        />
```