# How to change styling of TextInput placeholder in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there a way to set `fontStyle: 'italic'` **only** for the `placeholder` of the TextInput in React Native?

looking [here at the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)  seems like you can only set a placeholder and placeholderTextColor.

Comment: nope.  would be glad to find a solution

Comment: well.. now I'm stuck with the same problem too..

Comment: if you need to change just the color, look [that anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658976/reactnative-textinput-placeholdertextcolor-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Improving on Daniel's answer for a more generic solution

```
class TextInput2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { placeholder: props.value.length == 0 }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(ev) {
    this.setState({ placeholder: ev.nativeEvent.text.length == 0 }); 
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(ev); 
  }
  render() {
    const { placeholderStyle, style, onChange, ...rest } = this.props;

    return <TextInput 
      {...rest} 
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      style={this.state.placeholder ? [style, placeholderStyle] : style}
      />
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextInput2 
  value={this.state.myText}
  style={{ fontFamily: "MyFont" }}
  placeholderStyle={{ fontFamily: "AnotherFont", borderColor: 'red' }}
/>
```

Comment: it gives this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_th
is2.state.myText') - Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @cheesus why not?

Comment: Because it uses 2300% more lines of code than the answer by Sebastián Lara.

Comment: @cheesus It also actually answers the OP's question correctly. OP acknowledges the presence of placeholderTextColor and specifically asks how to style other properties. Also this answer was written before hooks but it should be trivial to convert to a hook-based alternative in fewer lines of code

Comment: Didn't notice that. However, I came from Google when googling how to set the placeholder color. Judging by the number of votes on the other answer, I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 71):

You can set your placeholder color by using the `placeholderTextColor` prop.

```
<TextInput placeholderTextColor={'red'} />
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, not the answer to the original question in this thread, but still.. helped me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: No it shouldn't be the accepted answer. They asked about changing the fontStyle not the color.

Answer (score 23):

You can build this functionality yourself. The placeholder is displayed when the input is empty, so you can check your state and change the fontStyle accordingly:

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={txt => this.setState({enteredText: txt})}
  fontStyle={this.state.enteredText.length == 0 ? 'italic' : 'normal'}
  style={style.input} />
```

For some reason this does not seem to work with fontFamily = System. So you have to explicitly specify the fontFamily.

Comment: onChange passes an event object, to get the text you should use `event.nativeEvent.text`

Comment: Or use onChangeText as it just passes the text

Comment: There is a lag in between first character typed and style update resulting in a visible jump in styles

Answer (score 9):

Content and placeHolder of TextInput use a common style, so you can set fontWeight and fontSize for placeHolder. For another, you can set property `placeholderTextColor` for `TextInput`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a stateless component.

Here's my solution:

First, in my screen component...

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import MyWrappedComponent from '../wherever/your/components/are/MyWrappedComponent';

class ScreenComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myText: null,
    };
    this.handleTextOnChange = this.handleTextOnChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTextOnChange(myText) {
    this.setState({ myText });
  }

  render() {
    const { myText } = this.state

  return (
    <View>
      <MyWrappedComponent            
        value={myText}
        placeholder="My Placeholder Text"
        onChangeText={this.handleTextOnChange}
        style={styles.someStyle}
        placeholderStyle={style.somePlaceholderStyle}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Then, in my wrapped component...

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const MyWrappedComponent = ({
  style,
  placeholderStyle,
  value,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <TextInput
    {...rest}
    style={!value ? [style, placeholderStyle] : style}
  />
);

export default MyWrappedComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to adjust your placeholder's positioning you can wrap the  inside a  and add styling to the :

```
<View style={{
    flex: 0.3,
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center"
    }}>
```

it'll allow the placeholder align to center as sometimes 'alignContent', 'alignItems', 'justifyContent' may not work.  Also:

```
inputContainerStyle={{
                    borderColor: 'transparent'
                }}
```

to style any border lines (the one above removes any borders coming from 'react-native-elements').

Answer (score 1):

I found that the styling that you assign to your text input will also apply to your placeholder text. The only property that you can set specific to the placeholder text is the color, other styling will be inherited from the text input styling.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at placeholder:

`TextInput` placeholder will inherit TextInput's styles. So we can set our Styles in the TextInput styles. sometimes we need a different color for placeholders, so we can easily use `placeholderTextColor` props for customizing.

Answer (score 0):

Passing in a component as the placeholder is what worked for me

Comment: I get an error when trying this: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'placeholder' of type 'object' supplied to 'ForwardRef(TextInput)', expected 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i was facing similar issue on how to style the placeholder. I was able to solve it using "placeholderTextColor". I hope this help also.

```
   <TextInput
      autoCorrect={false}
      secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
      keyboardType={keyboardType}
      onFocus={() => {
        onFocus();
        setIsFocused(true);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        setIsFocused(false);
      }}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      clearButtonMode="always"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      style={{padding: 10}}
      placeholderTextColor= "#475569"
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change in textInputStyle, placeholder style will change to the same with textInputStyle, and you wanna change color use placeholderTextColor

Comment: Please read questions carefully. OP wants the change "only for the placeholder" and is already aware of placeholderTextColor.