# React Native SearchBar placeholder alignment

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-elements Searchbar and want the placeholder on the right, and the text entry on the left.

It appears that you can only use text align to determine where to type, so I attempted to use a state to make the text on the left, placholder on the right. But this solution doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my opinion it just cannot be done

Comment: you may can create custom searchbar element for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native Elements supports styles similar to the [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) along with their own [props](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#props).

Since there is no prop to style the placeholder in `react-native's` textinput`as well as`searchbar`, therefore it cannot be done just with the styles.

However I can suggest you to make a separate instance of react-native-element `SearchBar` and pass your CustomTextInput component that contains the `placeholder styles` as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764112/6606831)

Comment: Ok, not that satisfying an answer but thank you for taking the time.