# React Native Custom TextInput Placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know you can dynamically change the Placeholder text and style, but can you create a custom Placeholder view all together?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You can create your own custom `TextInput` component

Comment: Could you perhaps post a small example how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change styling of TextInput placeholder in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581548/how-to-change-styling-of-textinput-placeholder-in-react-native)

Comment: @cnps Doubt it, that answers how to style it, but in the screen shot I added you can see there are two different colors, and it doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to use custom style with the functional component.Create a functional component called `RenderInput` for which pass `placeholder` as props.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const RenderInput = ({ label , inputvalue,styleLabel, ipOnChangeText, placeholder}) => {
    const {inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle} = styles;
    return(
        <View style = {containerStyle}>
            <Text style= {styleLabel ? labelStyle : ""} >{label}</Text>
            <TextInput 
               autoCorrect={false}
               placeholder={placeholder}
               style= {inputStyle}
            />
        </View>
    );
 }

const styles ={
    inputStyle:{
        color: '#333',
        fontSize: 16,
        lineHeight: 23,  
        borderBottomColor: '#333',
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        fontFamily: 'System',
    },
    labelStyle:{
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#737373',
        paddingBottom: 10,
        fontFamily: 'System',
        position: 'relative',
        ':after': {
           content: '* ',
           position: absolute,
           left: 5,
           top: 0,
           color: '#bbb'
        }
    },
    containerStyle:{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
    }
}
export { RenderInput };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer, however I'm using React Native not a web app. Is there a way to use that in React Native app?

Comment: I see that the answer is edited for React Native. I will only be able to test tomorrow but it looks good!

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this

```
<TextInput 
  placeholder="YOUR TEXT"
  placeholderTextColor="#555555"
/>
```

OR of course you can create your own version of the component TextInput something that contains the custom placeholder on top of the TextInput and once the text change you hide the custom placeholder