# Why placeholder text is also become bold if I applied that prop to only input text? (Android device)

Tags: react-native

I have manage new textinput too also tried different logics to maintain styling for textinput but not working on Android.
I want to know how should I apply two different style for input text and placeholder text.
I want to apply to different styles for placholdet text and input text.

[React Native Custom TextInput Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761887/react-native-custom-textinput-placeholder)

I tried this too and also tried react-native-elements  component too...

Here is my code

```
export default class TextInput2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { placeholder: props.value.length == 0 }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        // console.log('hello')
        // console.log(this.state.placeholder)
        // console.log(this.props.value)
        // console.log(this.props.value.length == 0)
        this.setState({
            placeholder: this.props.value.length == 0
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        // console.log('Update',this.props.value.length == 0)
        console.log(this.props.value)
    }
    handleChange(ev) {
      this.setState({ placeholder: ev.nativeEvent.text.length == 0 }); 
      this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(ev); 
    }
    handleTextChange(text){
        this.setState({ placeholder: text.length == 0 }); 
        this.props.onChangeText && this.props.onChangeText(text); 
    }
    render() {
      const { placeholderStyle, style, onChange, onChangeText,value, ...rest  } = this.props;
      let textstyle=''; 
      if(this.props.value.length == 0){
        console.log('in if',this.props.value.length == 0)
            textstyle = placeholderStyle
       }else{
           console.log('in else',this.props.value.length == 0 )
           textstyle=style
       }
      return <TextInput 
        {...rest}
        value={value} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onChangeText={(text)=>this.handleTextChange(text)}
        style={textstyle}
        />
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581548/how-to-change-styling-of-textinput-placeholder-in-react-native

Comment: its not working at all for android device.
i want to apply bold text when user input text and when its empty it should be normal.
its working fine in iOS but not in android.
@ Wen W