# Problem with placeholder styling in TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styles, placeholder

I've got a problem with styling of placeholder in TextInput. I want to have other font that default. Below i paste part of my code. Thanks for help and your time :)

I try add property placeholderStyle={{ fontFamily: "italic", borderColor: 'blue', paddingLeft: 200 }}

```
<Animated.View style={{paddingTop: 300, opacity: this.state.inputsOpacity, width: '90%', position: "absolute"}}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholderStyle={{ fontFamily: "italic", borderColor: 'blue', paddingLeft: 200 }} 
                    placeholder="Enter your email!"
                    style={{
                    borderBottomWidth: 2,
                    borderBottomColor: "black",
                    textAlignVertical: "center",
                    paddingLeft: 10,
                    height: 50
                }}></TextInput>
            </Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder is shown when the Textfield is empty . So you can check the state of TextField's value and then set the style for the placeholder accordingly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581548/how-to-change-styling-of-textinput-placeholder-in-react-native) link has more details